# Cascade type PERSIST doesn't work in @ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In the Spring Boot app with Hibernate and MySQL, I have an entity for comments. A comment can have child comments. So the entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
...
public class Comment extends AbstractAuditingModel {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Comment parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Comment> children = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I thought that with a configuration like this the hibernate should update the list of children in parent comment if a new comment with a set parent has been created. But no. So I'll try to explain what I mean with a code example.

```
Comment parent = new Comment();
parent = commentRepository.save(parent);

Comment child = new Comment();
child.setParent(parent);
commentRepository.save(child);

Comment parentFromDb = commentRepository.getOne(parent.getId());
List<Comment> children = parentFromDb.getChildren();

assert children != null && children.size() == 1;
```

So I thought it should work, but the only way it works is by using *entityManager.refresh(parentFromDB)* before getting children. How does it work without injecting the *entityManager*?

I don't want to add children to the parent's list and then to save this parent because in the abstract the parent's list can contain a lot of children. I suppose It will be bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

> Normally, Hibernate holds the persistable state in memory. The process
> of synchronizing this state to the underlying DB is called flushing.
>
> When we use the save() method, the data associated with the save
> operation will not be flushed to the DB unless and until an explicit
> call to flush() or commit() method is made.

from [save vs saveAndFlush article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush)

So you can either call `commentRepository.flush();` after you have saved those 2 comments

```
Comment parent = new Comment();
parent = commentRepository.save(parent);

Comment child = new Comment();
child.setParent(parent);
commentRepository.save(child);

commentRepository.flush();     <---add the flush here

Comment parentFromDb = commentRepository.getOne(parent.getId());
List<Comment> children = parentFromDb.getChildren();

assert children != null && children.size() == 1;
```

Or directly call saveAndFlush when you save those entities

```
Comment parent = new Comment();
parent = commentRepository.saveAndFlush(parent);

Comment child = new Comment();
child.setParent(parent);
commentRepository.saveAndFlush(child);

Comment parentFromDb = commentRepository.getOne(parent.getId());
List<Comment> children = parentFromDb.getChildren();
```

Also don't forget to add `@Transactional` to that method

Comment: Unfortunately it works not like this. Even with @Transactional children list ist null. Until now I have only one "solutions": entityManager.refresh(parent). But I think Hibernate should be able to synchronize parent after creating a child without additional actions.

Comment: try switching to `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` and run the provided solution here once again

Answer (score 0):

if your repository is a CrudRepository try the following

```
Comment parent = new Comment();
parent = commentRepository.save(parent);

Comment child = new Comment();
child.setParent(parent);
commentRepository.save(child);
commentRepository.flush();

Comment parentFromDb = commentRepository.findById(parent.getId()).get();
List<Comment> children = parentFromDb.getChildren();

assert children != null && children.size() == 1;
```

repository.getOne did not work because it was not reloading the parent from the database.